# How in DRF serializer to accept related object by ID on write and return the serialized object on read by same key?

Tags: django-rest-framework

Currently, my serializer looks like this:

```
from rest_framework.fields import UUIDField
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer

class StreetSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    city = CitySerializer(read_only=True)
    city_id = UUIDField(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Street
        fields = (
            'id',
            'city',
            'city_id',
            'name'
        )
```

When I create street, I send this JSON:

```
{'name': 'Elm', 'city_id': 'cc96aabf-a6e9-48fa-a3b4-6c487b8f3366'}'
```

and get this:

```
{'name': 'Elm', 'city': {'name': 'Dallas'}}
```

I wish to use same `city` key for both purposes in same create/update requests e.g.:

on POST

```
{'name': 'Elm', 'city': 'cc96aabf-a6e9-48fa-a3b4-6c487b8f3366'}'
```

I wish to get 201 response with content:

```
{'name': 'Elm', 'city': {'name': 'Dallas'}}
```

Comment: I think you can override create method in serializers

Comment: It will fail validation in this case. It expects JSON but I will send ID.

Comment: you can change the key when creating or updating related to model but you can send same key in payload, if you want, i can give you an example if you want

Comment: Sure, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Remove city_id from your serializers and fields too.

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    city_id = validated_data.pop('city')  # here you can pop key named city
    city = City.objects.get(id=city_id)   # getting instance of city obj
    street = Street.objects.create(city=city, **validated_data)
    return street
```

**Note**: Make sure your validated data contain all required field. Same you can override the update method like this:

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    .... remaining logic here 

    instance.save()
    return instance
```